How do I make sound in specific locations in Unity 3D?
I wanna make my first horror game, where player, when he goes out of the path, hears a specific sound. I made a "Fence" by using ProBuilder, result is on the first photo.
How the map looks
Inspector menu of the map
The main problem is that sound plays even if player didn't enter the collider.
I used the code, where player enters the fence and the fence enters player. Both variants gave the same result.
Code of the map]
Part of the player's code
How can I make my idea to come true?

Maybe you need to uncheck the Convex  on the collider?

Convex stretches the collider over the object.
If you uncheck this box, the object's collider will take the shape of the object itself. It's hard to see your fence, but it looks like this is the problem


But if I do, the player won't be able to go through the wall and sound won't play
